# While using PHPMailer in Joomla to send email with CC is not working correctly

Tags: php, joomla, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send emails in my Joomla project. When I send emails with to and cc both addresses, both the persons receive the email but in the email we can see only the person whose name was on to. It feels as if that person has been sent as to be a 'bcc' and hence not shown in the email. This behavior is a bit weird.

Any help here would be great.

Following is the code:

```
class EmailService {

    public function __construct($from_address = NULL, $from_name = NULL) {
        $config = & JFactory::getConfig();
        $from_address = isset($from_address) ? $from_address : $config->getValue('config.mailfrom');
        $from_name = isset($from_name) ? $from_name : $config->getValue('config.fromname');
        $sender = array(
            $from_address,
            $from_name
        );

        $this->mailer = JFactory::getMailer ( );
        $this->mailer->setSender($sender);
    }

       public function sendMail($recipient, $subject, $body, $type = 'html', $cc = null, $bcc = null, $attachment = null, $replyto = null, $replytoname = null) {
        if (!isset($this->mailer)) {
            throw new Exception("No mailer instance found!");
        }

        $this->mailer->addRecipient($recipient);
        $this->mailer->setSubject($subject);
        $this->mailer->setBody($body);

        if ($type == "html") {
            $this->mailer->isHTML(true);
        }

        if (isset($cc)) {
            $this->mailer->addCC($cc);
        }

        if (isset($bcc)) {
            $this->mailer->addBCC($bcc);
        }

        if (isset($attachment)) {
            $this->mailer->addAttachment($attachment);
        }

        if (is_array($replyto)) {
            $numReplyTo = count($replyto);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $numReplyTo; $i++) {
                $this->mailer->addReplyTo(array($replyto[$i], $replytoname[$i]));
            }
        } elseif (isset($replyto)) {
            $this->mailer->addReplyTo(array($replyto, $replytoname));
        }


        return $send = & $this->mailer->Send();
    }
```

[EDIT]
Following is snippet of the usage

```
$recipient = array ("abc@abc.com");
$cc = array ("cc@cc.com");
$emailType = 'html';
$emailBody = "Some HTML content";

$this->emailService->sendMail($recipient, "Some Subject", $emailBody, $emailType, $cc);
```

Comment: Can you paste code where you use this function? Its looks correct, so maybe your call is wrong?

Comment: Hi jdog I have edited above to include the code where I use this method.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, maybe try copying in a newer (or different) version of phpmailer into Joomla? OR turn on debugging of phpmailer to see what is happening. Best to look at this with a debugger

Comment: @bluekant Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm having a similar one with PHPMailer.

Comment: can you add a debug print to class EmailService that prints the parameters that you send to sendMail() ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the default Joomla mailer?

```
$mailer =& JFactory::getMailer();
```

[Joomla documentation for JMail](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_send_email_from_components)

Comment: If you see the above code, you may see that is what I was using.